# Why are some .js file diffs not shown inline in sourcetree?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I get a weird behavior in SourceTree when i do commit comparisons.

For most files, i get a small preview of the changes, grouped in "hunks". This is a great way of seeing the changes i made to the files and it even lets me revert parts/hunks of a files changes.

It seemingly works for both some .js files and .html and even .asp files. Except, some specific .js files never show up in the preview. SourceTree correctly marks them as added, changed etc in the log/history but it won't show a diff preview. Using an external diff tool (i use Beyond Compare) works perfectly and i can view the changes there. The problem is, i don't want to launch the external compare when the nifty preview works so well.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the encoding of the files matter. My "Unicode" (read 16bit) files are not previewed, while UTF-8 files ("mixed" 8/16 bit) will get previewed - atleast in the cases i tested.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to check your SourceTree config.

Under "Diff" tab, there are max file size settings for text/binary files.

Answer (score 0):

Use git diff --cached. 
It works.

Comment: That looks like a commandline fix. How do you use that in sourcetree ?